# Visual Studio C++ 2010 How to add an ICON to a console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, icons

I've created a console application in Visual Studio C++ 2010 but I cannot add an Icon. Ive basically searched everywhere but all the tips and hints seem to not be working, as I cant even find all the menus that are suggested in the tips Ive read (Probably for older versions of VC++ 2010).

Does anyone have a good tip on how to simply add a custom icon to my own console application?

Answer (score 10):

Just create a resource file (.rc), and add an icon resource. If there's only one icon in it- it will automatically be used as a symbolic description to your application.